# Adding Rate button in app confusion

Tags: ios, button, rate

My app isn't in the app store yet, in fact I haven't even uploaded it to iTunes Connect yet. I want to add a rate button in my iOS game. Rate button usually takes the user from the app to the link in the app store for your game. How do I add a rate button if my app is not in the app store yet since I don't have a link to the app store where my game would be.

Is there another way to add a rate button without my game being in the app store. Can the Rate button only be added when the App is in the app store (after release) or are there other ways before the app is in app store?

I know I'm going to have to use...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

But what goes inside that string since my app is not in app store but I do have iTunes connect setup however for development at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your app in Itunes Connect and you will be given an App ID. You can use this App ID to reference your app on the itunes app store:

> `http://itunes.apple.com/app/idyourID`

Be sure to include `id` in front of your id number. I.e, `id123456789`

Another way would be to have your link in the cloud DB somewhere (i.e. Parse) and when the app is released update the link, but that would be overkill for this situation.

Comment: I read around on this site to use App ID. However, even at launch of the app, do I stick to the app ID or do I change it once the app is already in App Store?

Comment: I would definitely stick with the App ID since it is a unique identifier to your app. An app name can always change but your App ID will always reference your apps itunes page.

Comment: Also see my update on how to implement a more dynamic URL in your app using Parse or some other cloud backend.

Comment: So just to be clear, with my unique App ID, when the app is released and the user clicks on the Rate button, they'll be automatically transferred to MY game's link in Apple Store and not just the front page or somewhere general in the Apple Store?

Comment: Right, when using the URL above, it will take the user to itunes page for the specified App ID. So in your case, it will take your users to your game's app store page.

Comment: Hey, I am a little stuck on this too. So the app ID is the 9 digit number you can find under "About this App" in iTunes connect right? I can create a UIButton "Rate" and link it to [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myAppID]]; Is this right?

Comment: Yes that is correct, although you would use the url in my answer with your App ID...be sure to put "id" in front as shown in the example.